# Get better performance for converting matrix to vector

Tags: performance, matlab

when working with images, usually they include 3 layers, (RGB). In order to do some computation, I need to convert each layer of the image into a vector.

```
I1 = ones(70,50,3);       % the first image
I2 = 0.4 * ones(70,50,3); % the second image
for dd = 1:3
    ILayer1 = I1(:,:,dd);
    ILayerLinear1 = ILayer1(:);
    ILayer2 = I2(:,:,dd);
    ILayerLinear2 = ILayer2(:);
    comp = ILayerLinear1 * ILayerLinear1.';
end
```

Here I have replaced the main computation part with a very simple computation, but that is not the point.
Is there a better way to not repeat the matrix-to-vector conversion, or do it more efficiently? Because it may happen multiple times through the code.

**Update:**

I can also define a function as follows to pass an Image and retrieve a vector, but it still is not improving the code.

```
function V = I2V(I)
[r,c,d] = size(I);
V = zeros(d,r*c);
for dd = 1:d
    layer = I(:,:,dd);
    V(dd,:) = layer(:);
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the outer product but, here's everything else.

```
I1 = reshape(1:70*50*3, 70,50,3);
I2 = 0.4*reshape(1:70*50*3, 70,50,3);

i1 = reshape(I1, [], 3);
i2 = reshape(I2, [], 3);
```